# Scalaz: How to use EitherInstances with MonadError?

Tags: scala, scalaz

I want to use `scala.util.Either` together with `scalaz.MonadError`, but I'm running into some type issues.
My simplest failing code is below:

```
object Foo extends EitherInstances {
  private val success: Either[String, Int] = Right(42)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    MonadError.apply(eitherMonad[String]).handleError[Int](success)(_ => Right(43))
  }
}
```

However, this results in the follow undecipherable errors:

```
Error:(10, 16) no type parameters for method apply: (implicit F: scalaz.MonadError[F,S])scalaz.MonadError[F,S] in object MonadError exist so that it can be applied to arguments (scalaz.Traverse[[β$0$]scala.util.Either[String,β$0$]] with scalaz.MonadError[[β$1$]scala.util.Either[String,β$1$],String] with scalaz.BindRec[[β$2$]scala.util.Either[String,β$2$]] with scalaz.Cozip[[β$3$]scala.util.Either[String,β$3$]])
 --- because ---
argument expression's type is not compatible with formal parameter type;
 found   : scalaz.Traverse[[β$0$]scala.util.Either[String,β$0$]] with scalaz.MonadError[[β$1$]scala.util.Either[String,β$1$],String] with scalaz.BindRec[[β$2$]scala.util.Either[String,β$2$]] with scalaz.Cozip[[β$3$]scala.util.Either[String,β$3$]]
 required: scalaz.MonadError[?F,?S]
    MonadError.apply(eitherMonad[String]).handleError[Int](success)(_ => Right(43))
Error:(10, 33) type mismatch;
 found   : scalaz.Traverse[[β$0$]scala.util.Either[String,β$0$]] with scalaz.MonadError[[β$1$]scala.util.Either[String,β$1$],String] with scalaz.BindRec[[β$2$]scala.util.Either[String,β$2$]] with scalaz.Cozip[[β$3$]scala.util.Either[String,β$3$]]
 required: scalaz.MonadError[F,S]
    MonadError.apply(eitherMonad[String]).handleError[Int](success)(_ => Right(43))
```

If I try to let the compiler infer the type, e.g., in the following code:

```
object Foo extends EitherInstances {
  private val success: Either[String, Int] = Right(42)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    MonadError.apply.handleError(success)(_ => Right(43))
  }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Error:(11, 16) could not find implicit value for parameter F: scalaz.MonadError[F,S]
MonadError.apply.handleError(success)(_ => Right(43))
Error:(11, 16) not enough arguments for method apply: (implicit F: scalaz.MonadError[F,S])scalaz.MonadError[F,S] in object MonadError.
Unspecified value parameter F.
    MonadError.apply.handleError(success)(_ => Right(43))
```

Since the result of `eitherMonad` explicitly declares itself to be a `MonadError`, I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong here. What do I need to do to convince the compiler that Either is indeed a `MonadError`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong here

You need to enable `Ypartial-unification` and the code will compile without any changes.

sbt:

```
scalacOptions in Compile ++= Seq("-Ypartial-unification")
```

---

You can also use `kind-projector` to alias a type lambda and help the compiler:

sbt:

```
addCompilerPlugin("org.spire-math" %% "kind-projector" % "0.9.4")
```

And then:

```
MonadError.apply[Either[String, ?], String].handleError(success)(_ => Right(43))
```

Comment: That works! Is there any way to make it compile without explicit types?

Comment: @Gal Yes, enabling partial unification (see the first part of my answer :))

Comment: I've tried that (removed the type parameters to `apply`), but it stops compiling unfortunately: `could not find implicit value for parameter F: scalaz.MonadError[F,S]`.

Comment: @Gal This works: `MonadError.apply(eitherMonad[String]).handleError[Int](success)(_ => Right(43))`, but you still provide the implicit explicitly :\

Comment: @Gal Note, that with partial unification, you can use the MonadError syntax and just write `success.handleError(_ => Right(43))`

Comment: That works. Do you know hut how I can get it to play nice with IntelliJ? It shows the code as red, but compiles and runs it just fine. I've tried adding `-Ypartial-unification` as a compiler flag to IntelliJ, but that didn't work.

Comment: @Gal That is a IntelliJ Scala plugin bugs. You can open a ticket.